# Meaning of "guiri"

Tags: sens

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series Marseille:

- Allez, les Guiris!

Context: a drug dealer is ordering two of his men to steal a car. These men are black and speak a foreign language, so they are probably immigrants or sons of immigrants.

I have not found this word in the Word Reference and Larousse dictionaries. I know that "guiri" is a slang used in Spain to refer to a foreigner. Does it have the same meaning in French?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wikipedia article [Le parler marseillais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parler_marseillais) mentions that the word "guirri" is used in Marseille and has been borrowed from Comorian; it means "someone strong, brave".

(rem: I am not at all a local from Marseille and had never heard/read this word before, so any comment from a native speaker of that region on the actual usage of this word is welcome).